# AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_output_tensor_cache'

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, mlp

```
import keras
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model
from keras_adamw import AdamW

mlp = Model([
        Dense(10, activation='relu', input_shape=trainX_scaled.shape), #input shape
        Dense(10,  activation='relu'),  #Hiddin layer
        Dense(10, activation='relu') #output layer
])

optimizer = AdamW(lr=0.001,model=mlp)
mlp.compile(optimizer, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = mlp.fit(trainX_scaled, train_y, epochs=500, validation_data=(valX_scaled, val_y), batch_size=1)
```

The error is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-46d3a15c03c4> in <module>()
     19 optimizer = AdamW(lr=0.001,model=mlp)
     20 mlp.compile(optimizer, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 21 history = mlp.fit(trainX_scaled, train_y, epochs=500, validation_data=(valX_scaled, val_y), batch_size=1)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py in call(self, inputs, mask)
    578         cache_key = object_list_uid(inputs)
    579         cache_key += '_' + object_list_uid(masks)
--> 580         if cache_key in self._output_tensor_cache:
    581             return self._output_tensor_cache[cache_key]
    582         else:

AttributeError: 'Model' object has no attribute '_output_tensor_cache'
```

The error occurs when running `model.fit`.

Answer (score 0):

Which tensorflow version have you installed in your system? Please import the keras libraries from `tensorflow.keras` and re-execute the above code.

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
```

`AdamW` api is part of `Tensorflow Addons` package. To import `AdamW` optimizer, you need to use below code:

```
!pip install tensorflow-addons
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
from tensorflow_addons.optimizers import AdamW
```

Or can simply use `Adam` optimizer instead of using `Adamw` as below:

```
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
```

Let us know if the issue still persists. Thank You.